# Filling a matrix randomnly

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following code that generate a matrix of size (i*2,j) filled with randomly with (0,1)

```
i=input('i:');
j=input('j:');
B=randi([0 1], i*2,j);
```

I want now to fill 4 lignes ( Position is not important ) in the middle of the previous matrix with zeros only. What is the fastest way to do that 
thank you .

Comment: In such cases, It's best to provide a small example of a matrix before and after the operation you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by lines, you mean rows then this should work:

```
B(5:8,:) = 0;
% Where 5:8 can be any values you want, this is just an example
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work by iterating 4 rows in the middle:

```
for k = i-2:i+2
    B(k,:) = 0
end
```

or the following should be a faster way:

```
B(i-2:i+2, :) = 0
```

given i*2 is your number of lines, hence i-2 to i+2 should be the middle four lines.